# Microsoft 365 access review for Teams: can an access review be assigned automatically to all teams when created?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft365

In azure can an access review policy for all members (not for guests only) be assigned automatically to all teams as they get created or is there only the option of creating a script that detects teams creation and for example via the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module cmdlets or making directly calls to microsoft graph creates or assigns to them an access review policy?

Below the UI in the Azure portal that shows that when interested in reviewing all user memberships (so not only guests) you are required to specify the groups/teams while my need would be to enable this review automatically on all groups/teams as they get created

[image]

Comment: You can review access to privileged roles using the access reviews API in Microsoft Graph.
Please refer below document for steps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorial-accessreviews-roleassignments?tabs=http

Comment: not looking for reviewing roles but only group/team memberships - when creating a new access review at least from the UI it seems that you can automatically enable a review for all groups/teams only to review guest members while if you want to have it applied to all members you are forced to specify the specific groups/teams - is there an option to create an access review for **all members** that applies automatically to **all groups/teams**?

Comment: Currently, there is no way to create an access review for all members that applies automatically to all groups/teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to create an access review for all members that applies automatically to all groups/teams.